# Are driver probe and remove methods in linux kernel executed in parallel for multiple devices?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Can someone please shed some light on driver `.probe` and `.remove` methods serialization?

For example if there are 10 PCIe cards attached to a server and there is a common driver to detect(probe) these 10 devices, then how is the probe function called?
Is it called in parallel for all the devices or executed one by one - meaning, the second call to probe won't happen until the first probe call for the first device returns?

Thanks,
Prathamesh

Comment: There was an attempt to add [such a feature](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0f397f865076e3471ec884ee73ad5e34165fac2a), but later it was [reverted](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5adc55da4a7758021bcc374904b0f8b076508a11). So at the moment kernel doesn't seem to provide multi-theaded probe support, not even for PCI bus.

Comment: @SamProtsenko, what about async probe? It's in the kernel and wasn't reverted as far as I know.

Comment: @0andriy Probably missed it, since those patches were merged not so long ago. Obviously you know this matter, so why don't you go ahead and answer the question?